# How to load a .jpg from an URI to canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to load a .jpg file on a canvas but it not working.

I'm using a code that works, but not with my image. Can someone help and explain what is happening?

This code does not show the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/mcepc44p/127/

This code show the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/mcepc44p/2/

The only difference between the fiddles is this:

In the first fiddle,

```
image.src = "https://img.olx.pt/images_olxpt/880146485_1_1000x700_conjunto-de-sofs-terno-em-couro-verdadeiro-lisboa.jpg"
```

and the last fiddle,

```
image.src = "https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/1691290368/h07F7F378/"
```

Some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: the issue is, the second site allows CORS, the first does not

Comment: Yeah, you say that `image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` enables CORS. Not if the site doesn't allow it, it doesn't.

Comment: _“Some clues?”_ – browser console!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a CORS problem.

Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Relevant here::

> This cross-origin sharing standard is used to enable cross-site HTTP requests for:
>
> - Images/video frames drawn to a canvas using drawImage

In short:
The server serving your the image in the second fiddle adds a Response Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, the first server doesn't.

This leads to your browser blocking the image from being drawn in a canvas element.

Comment: Thanks. I've done the request from an image in my server and it works. Thanks!

Comment: "*This leads to your browser blocking the image from being drawn in a canvas element.'* That's not true. It leads the browsers supporting the crossOrigin attribute to fire an error event and not load the image at all. It's not only related to canvas.

Answer (score 2):

The second site sends this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
```

Which enables cross origin requests. It's down to the server to dictate whether its assets can be accessed via cross origin requests, not the client.

The first site does not send this header at all, therefore disallowing your cross origin request. So, you are incapable of doing what you wish to do with that image because of this.

Further info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 0):

The image will load and display. The issue is that you attempt to get the data contained in the image which then throws a security error. If you remove the `canvas.toDataURL` you will be able to display the image. If you wish to download it just set the download link ref to the image URL

Comment: If the crossOrigin attribute is set and that the server doesn't send the proper headers, the image will throw an error and never load.