# Is it possible to put a jpg image into a canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to create a game in javascript and I wanted to use a jpg image I've drawn as a sprite and put it into a canvas, then further control the sprite to make it move left and right, but I can't seem to figure out how to let the image show in the canvas

I've searched up some similar questions such as this: [How to add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)
The image I am adding is not from a browser but a downloaded image on the desktop of my computer.

I used the code in the above solution but it does not show the image

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'pic.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I do not want the image to be a background but rather an image that can be used as a character(like a sprite in a game). Is there any other solutions to this problems or is there anything I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a .jpg from an URI to canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126143/how-to-load-a-jpg-from-an-uri-to-canvas)

Comment: Is there any other image or something that could be messing with your image? The code is fine, but there's something else messing up. Probably a CORS problem (like in the post from the above comment)

Comment: If you want to make a game, i would suggest you look into pixi.js. It's a javascript 2D game engine that easy handles such things for you.

Comment: @kai Lehmann I'll look into it, thanks